# Using gratia::smooth_estimates() with a tensor to produce a heatmap for a defined area (e.g., US state lines) in R

Tags: r, heatmap, tensor, gam, mgcv

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
  structure(list(count = c(85970L, 57321L, 46409L, 30436L, 47316L, 
2037L, 82188L, 127510L, 97109L, 15328L, 37766L, 74320L, 197130L, 
73258L, 27795L, 52434L, 124762L, 16471L, 22938L, 23192L, 269932L, 
69908L, 22480L, 180249L, 1771L, 66598L, 39182L, 46038L, 61145L, 
152175L, 1399L, 134424L, 43606L, 2221L, 43559L, 11684L, 12566L, 
180520L, 101116L, 69597L, 13915L, 7268L, 3427L, 96646L, 46133L, 
12031L, 13757L, 59464L, 32686L, 130545L, 322294L, 79400L, 148609L, 
100379L, 137641L, 461L, 162990L, 141629L, 8291L, 47033L, 167593L, 
232321L, 59686L, 64641L, 273107L, 138242L, 3891L, 139969L, 105676L, 
219271L, 24154L, 236896L, 44177L, 78308L, 72062L, 1708L, 106882L, 
53302L, 104267L, 123396L, 9971L, 82740L, 98013L, 17759L, 2338L, 
210581L, 77454L, 89777L, 304L, 303330L, 11536L, 13508L, 65698L, 
65678L, 168244L, 137721L, 128938L, 45270L, 12065L, 4788L, 29950L, 
84208L, 2938L, 2226L, 288115L, 34381L, 29622L, 32731L, 81229L, 
29917L, 52117L, 51471L, 55578L, 72827L, 4353L, 117578L, 41764L, 
108096L, 4978L, 24245L, 64693L, 95385L, 39591L, 18504L, 65459L, 
81650L, 248L, 55279L, 30344L, 84002L, 44458L, 48848L, 10242L, 
143527L, 5219L, 5684L, 124091L, 14563L, 22661L, 24415L, 78820L, 
5137L, 30521L, 30628L, 85572L, 3111L, 3772L, 88998L, 15453L, 
4040L, 38177L, 5006L, 1378L, 28548L, 97929L, 75099L, 58L, 32857L, 
3911L, 7545L, 4066L, 57735L, 11788L, 8526L, 66760L, 29170L, 92913L, 
53435L, 5395L, 35459L, 21655L, 3467L, 27090L, 16361L, 57477L, 
38412L, 126957L, 20936L, 14252L, 74194L, 51816L, 11702L, 14601L, 
21749L, 975L, 11135L, 1241L, 7758L, 39140L, 12575L, 37743L, 19391L, 
30211L, 38409L, 12963L, 102396L, 18964L, 110808L, 49L, 9085L, 
6728L, 66610L, 16165L, 3075L, 17844L, 49640L, 47995L, 16246L, 
59423L, 17876L, 75570L, 1384L, 10572L, 41492L, 51660L), Longitude = c(-95.53558, 
-94.08706, -93.5671, -98.24354, -95.53558, -96.09736, -94.08706, 
-93.5671, -101.05749, -96.06779, -98.24354, -95.53558, -94.08706, 
-93.5671, -98.24354, -95.53558, -94.08706, -93.5671, -98.24354, 
-95.53558, -94.08706, -93.5671, -98.24354, -95.53558, -96.09736, 
-94.08706, -93.5671, -95.53558, -95.53558, -94.08706, -98.24354, 
-93.5671, -95.53558, -96.09736, -94.08706, -96.06779, -98.24354, 
-95.53558, -93.5671, -95.53558, -95.53558, -96.96682, -96.09736, 
-94.08706, -96.57169, -93.5671, -95.53558, -96.57169, -99.1598, 
-95.53558, -94.08706, -93.5671, -101.05749, -98.24354, -95.53558, 
-96.09736, -94.08706, -93.5671, -96.06779, -98.24354, -95.53558, 
-94.08706, -93.5671, -98.24354, -95.53558, -94.08706, -95.90206, 
-93.5671, -98.24354, -95.53558, -97.0545, -93.5671, -98.24354, 
-99.1598, -95.53558, -96.09736, -94.08706, -93.5671, -101.05749, 
-95.53558, -96.96682, -93.5671, -95.53558, -98.24354, -95.90206, 
-93.5671, -101.05749, -95.53558, -96.09736, -94.08706, -96.06779, 
-98.24354, -99.1598, -95.53558, -93.5671, -95.53558, -101.05749, 
-98.24354, -97.0545, -95.90206, -99.1598, -95.53558, -96.96682, 
-96.09736, -94.08706, -96.57169, -98.24354, -96.57169, -93.5671, 
-95.53558, -95.53558, -94.08706, -93.5671, -95.53558, -96.09736, 
-94.08706, -93.5671, -101.05749, -96.06779, -98.24354, -95.53558, 
-94.08706, -93.5671, -98.24354, -95.53558, -94.08706, -95.90206, 
-93.5671, -98.24354, -95.53558, -94.08706, -93.5671, -98.24354, 
-95.53558, -97.0545, -96.09736, -94.08706, -93.5671, -96.06779, 
-98.24354, -95.53558, -96.96682, -93.5671, -95.53558, -94.08706, 
-98.24354, -95.90206, -93.5671, -95.53558, -96.09736, -94.08706, 
-96.06779, -98.24354, -95.53558, -93.5671, -95.53558, -95.90206, 
-95.53558, -96.96682, -97.0545, -96.09736, -94.08706, -96.06779, 
-99.1598, -96.57169, -93.5671, -95.53558, -96.57169, -95.53558, 
-94.08706, -93.5671, -98.24354, -99.1598, -95.53558, -94.08706, 
-93.5671, -101.05749, -98.24354, -95.53558, -94.08706, -93.5671, 
-98.24354, -95.53558, -94.08706, -95.90206, -93.5671, -98.24354, 
-95.53558, -93.5671, -98.24354, -95.53558, -94.08706, -93.5671, 
-99.1598, -95.53558, -101.05749, -95.53558, -94.08706, -95.90206, 
-93.5671, -95.53558, -94.08706, -101.05749, -98.24354, -95.53558, 
-93.5671, -99.1598, -95.53558, -101.05749, -98.24354, -94.08706, 
-96.57169, -96.57169, -93.5671, -98.24354), Latitude = c(32.80818, 
31.06582, 31.17619, 28.4825, 32.80818, 31.95728, 31.06582, 31.17619, 
29.45031, 32.18075, 28.4825, 32.80818, 31.06582, 31.17619, 28.4825, 
32.80818, 31.06582, 31.17619, 28.4825, 32.80818, 31.06582, 31.17619, 
28.4825, 32.80818, 31.95728, 31.06582, 31.17619, 32.80818, 32.80818, 
31.06582, 28.4825, 31.17619, 32.80818, 31.95728, 31.06582, 32.18075, 
28.4825, 32.80818, 31.17619, 32.80818, 32.80818, 33.06952, 31.95728, 
31.06582, 33.81821, 31.17619, 32.80818, 33.81821, 26.55788, 32.80818, 
31.06582, 31.17619, 29.45031, 28.4825, 32.80818, 31.95728, 31.06582, 
31.17619, 32.18075, 28.4825, 32.80818, 31.06582, 31.17619, 28.4825, 
32.80818, 31.06582, 32.82516, 31.17619, 28.4825, 32.80818, 33.35353, 
31.17619, 28.4825, 26.55788, 32.80818, 31.95728, 31.06582, 31.17619, 
29.45031, 32.80818, 33.06952, 31.17619, 32.80818, 28.4825, 32.82516, 
31.17619, 29.45031, 32.80818, 31.95728, 31.06582, 32.18075, 28.4825, 
26.55788, 32.80818, 31.17619, 32.80818, 29.45031, 28.4825, 33.35353, 
32.82516, 26.55788, 32.80818, 33.06952, 31.95728, 31.06582, 33.81821, 
28.4825, 33.81821, 31.17619, 32.80818, 32.80818, 31.06582, 31.17619, 
32.80818, 31.95728, 31.06582, 31.17619, 29.45031, 32.18075, 28.4825, 
32.80818, 31.06582, 31.17619, 28.4825, 32.80818, 31.06582, 32.82516, 
31.17619, 28.4825, 32.80818, 31.06582, 31.17619, 28.4825, 32.80818, 
33.35353, 31.95728, 31.06582, 31.17619, 32.18075, 28.4825, 32.80818, 
33.06952, 31.17619, 32.80818, 31.06582, 28.4825, 32.82516, 31.17619, 
32.80818, 31.95728, 31.06582, 32.18075, 28.4825, 32.80818, 31.17619, 
32.80818, 32.82516, 32.80818, 33.06952, 33.35353, 31.95728, 31.06582, 
32.18075, 26.55788, 33.81821, 31.17619, 32.80818, 33.81821, 32.80818, 
31.06582, 31.17619, 28.4825, 26.55788, 32.80818, 31.06582, 31.17619, 
29.45031, 28.4825, 32.80818, 31.06582, 31.17619, 28.4825, 32.80818, 
31.06582, 32.82516, 31.17619, 28.4825, 32.80818, 31.17619, 28.4825, 
32.80818, 31.06582, 31.17619, 26.55788, 32.80818, 29.45031, 32.80818, 
31.06582, 32.82516, 31.17619, 32.80818, 31.06582, 29.45031, 28.4825, 
32.80818, 31.17619, 26.55788, 32.80818, 29.45031, 28.4825, 31.06582, 
33.81821, 33.81821, 31.17619, 28.4825), offset = c(134328, 50282, 
46878, 57535.7, 100672, 4851, 70913, 55199, 121690, 15688.6, 
59288, 124281, 148777, 57957, 34830.9, 100834, 102516, 16389, 
34754.9, 56566, 197031, 51976, 26140, 130615, 1265, 58063, 31598, 
86864, 83759.9, 80516, 3515, 80735, 118817.9, 8541, 36604, 14642, 
10385, 311241.8, 65447, 92796, 36618, 18682.6, 9520, 74343, 62342, 
15057, 60602.9, 77226, 19514, 334731, 441498, 107881, 135099, 
109226.6, 382337, 5120, 235195, 114494, 24031, 75859.8, 478836, 
219171, 76915, 72063, 666114, 134346, 6949, 188637, 108274.8, 
261037, 58912, 230915, 50778.6, 47749, 135966, 5177, 63696, 80761, 
128092, 224357, 22207, 70718, 297008.8, 22282, 1635, 243728, 
140824.7, 272053, 2170, 167493, 16622.5, 14844, 49397, 184488.7, 
141263, 237449.6, 127915.1, 33783.9, 43091, 25200, 85572, 255177, 
17917.5, 7420, 198700, 52093, 38470, 35968, 128730, 57533, 121202, 
91912, 74601, 137409, 17411, 113492, 48226, 136830, 4818.6, 46005, 
143763, 114234, 43175, 21516, 176916, 70388, 2252, 50026, 45289.7, 
155560, 56997, 46969, 35316.6, 146456, 20876, 10526, 95602, 28169, 
35519, 23704, 99898.9, 7275.6, 24693, 69608.5, 66335, 8407, 12572, 
83488, 67187, 8595, 46444, 5193, 10060, 135945, 72540, 111847.9, 
583, 88803, 8409.9, 20392, 11294, 56327, 15113, 22435.6, 71785, 
30803, 244507, 95419, 29974, 48112, 29264, 11955.7, 22957.7, 
68170, 117780, 61955, 208126, 46523.8, 39590, 87287, 32962, 37750, 
39461, 25953, 8128, 19884, 14262.5, 48487, 32918, 20959, 65074, 
48968, 46839, 51903.9, 29462, 153058, 46252.8, 110974, 2439, 
10094, 42050.6, 78828, 57733.9, 7501, 137263.9, 67081, 61532, 
29538.9, 78188.5, 9508.5, 85583, 11530, 42289, 73050, 53812.6
), name = structure(c(5L, 9L, 12L, 3L, 5L, 8L, 9L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 3L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 3L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 3L, 5L, 8L, 
9L, 12L, 5L, 5L, 9L, 3L, 12L, 5L, 8L, 9L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 12L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 5L, 11L, 4L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 
8L, 9L, 12L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 3L, 5L, 9L, 10L, 12L, 3L, 5L, 
7L, 12L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 9L, 12L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 12L, 5L, 3L, 10L, 
12L, 1L, 5L, 8L, 9L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 12L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 10L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 3L, 11L, 12L, 5L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 5L, 8L, 
9L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 3L, 5L, 9L, 10L, 12L, 3L, 5L, 
9L, 12L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 12L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 12L, 5L, 9L, 
3L, 10L, 12L, 5L, 8L, 9L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 12L, 5L, 10L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 2L, 4L, 11L, 12L, 5L, 11L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 9L, 
12L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 3L, 5L, 9L, 10L, 12L, 3L, 5L, 12L, 
3L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 10L, 12L, 5L, 9L, 1L, 3L, 
5L, 12L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 9L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 3L), .Label = c("Ami", 
"Ced", "Cho", "Fal", "For", "Lew", "Ray", "Ric", "Sam", "Taw", 
"Tex", "Tol"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(3L, 6L, 7L, 
9L, 12L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 24L, 25L, 28L, 30L, 
33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 39L, 41L, 45L, 46L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 54L, 60L, 
62L, 64L, 68L, 72L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 80L, 83L, 89L, 90L, 
92L, 93L, 96L, 97L, 100L, 103L, 109L, 110L, 115L, 116L, 118L, 
121L, 124L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 141L, 142L, 145L, 
147L, 153L, 154L, 155L, 157L, 158L, 161L, 163L, 169L, 170L, 171L, 
174L, 175L, 176L, 178L, 179L, 181L, 185L, 190L, 196L, 203L, 204L, 
206L, 211L, 212L, 213L, 214L, 215L, 216L, 217L, 219L, 224L, 229L, 
232L, 235L, 236L, 239L, 240L, 242L, 244L, 245L, 246L, 247L, 249L, 
250L, 253L, 255L, 259L, 260L, 263L, 267L, 268L, 269L, 270L, 272L, 
273L, 274L, 278L, 279L, 282L, 284L, 287L, 288L, 289L, 290L, 291L, 
295L, 297L, 300L, 301L, 304L, 305L, 306L, 307L, 311L, 312L, 313L, 
314L, 316L, 320L, 323L, 325L, 330L, 331L, 335L, 337L, 338L, 339L, 
340L, 341L, 343L, 346L, 351L, 353L, 354L, 356L, 357L, 358L, 361L, 
362L, 364L, 365L, 368L, 371L, 375L, 377L, 378L, 380L, 382L, 383L, 
385L, 386L, 387L, 390L, 391L, 392L, 393L, 395L, 397L, 400L, 401L, 
402L, 403L, 404L, 407L, 411L, 412L, 415L, 416L, 418L, 419L, 423L, 
426L, 427L, 430L, 431L, 434L, 435L, 436L, 437L, 438L, 439L, 442L, 
443L, 449L, 450L, 452L, 453L, 456L, 457L, 458L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am running a gam that looks like this:

```
library(mgcv)
mod1<-gam(count~te(Longitude,Latitude)+offset(log(offset))+s(name,bs="re"),family=nb, data=data)
```

Now I am trying to do a few things with this tensor as a heatmap and am wondering a few things. My current output looks like this with state lines (data are within the state of Texas):

```
library(gratia)
library(maps)
library(fields)
library(ggplot2)    
state_map <- map_data("state")
bmap=map_data("state", xlim=c(-102,-95), ylim=c(20,32))

sm <- smooth_estimates(mod1, smooth = "te(Longitude,Latitude)",partial_match=T)

draw(sm) + 
  coord_fixed(ratio = 1) +
  geom_polygon(data=bmap,aes(x=long,y=lat,group=group), inherit.aes=F, 
               colour='black', fill=NA, lwd=1) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) + 
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white',color="black"),
        legend.key = element_blank())
```

[image]

What I am wondering is if there is a way to take this smooth estimate and confine the the predictions within a certain area (e.g., state lines)? For this example, all of my data are within the confines of Texas state lines but the area with the greatest impact on counts (the southeast corner of the state) is not truly represented by this heat map as the area with the highest effect is over the ocean where there were no counts at all.

I am also noticing that the original output from the `draw(mod1)` command looks different from the `smooth_estimate` output. See below:

[image]

If there is not a way to confine predictions within bounds (e.g., state lines), how do I get the original output that I see with the command `draw(mod1)` within a smooth estimate so that I can overlay this output with state lines to orient the viewer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To confine the output from `smooth_estimates()` to be as per the `draw()` output, in your call to `smooth_estimates()`, set the `dist` argument to the required value. The `draw()` method for `"gam"` objects used `dist = 0.1` for example.

If you want to confine the smooth to the state boundary as well / instead, then you'll need to set the values of `est` in `sm` where `Longitude` and `Latitude` are outside the Texas state boundary to `NA`. I'm not sure how to do that exactly with data from the *map* package but there will be a way to treat the Texas boundary as a polygon and then ask if each of your point locations (`Longitude` and `Latitude`) at which the smooth was evaluated lies within that polygon. Any that don't should have the respective row in `sm` set to `NA`.